# How can I implement “semi-supervised” classifier in C#

Tags: c#, text-mining, accord.net

I am working on text-mining to use Accord.net; I have more unlabeled data. I hence need a C# implementation of “semi-supervised” classifier.

So my questions are :

1. Is it possible implement “semi-supervised” classifier in Accord.Net
2. Do you know of a other package which already implement c# “semi-supervised” classifier

Thank you
regards.

Comment: There are currently no semi-supervised learning algorithms in Accord.NET, but if you give an example on which one you would be interested, it is always possible to open a [feature request in the project issue tracker to get it implemented](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues).